# Open\Close all Files in a Folder based on Specific text in the name like "MTD" "YTD" "DataExtract" and "MainFile"

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I am trying to create two separate loops in VBA. One to open all files in a folder based on specific text such as "MTD", "YTD","MainFile" and "DataExtract." Then separately, when I want to, close all open files with those same text strings. I currently only have a functioning loop to open all files with .xlsx in a cell value on the active sheet. I do not have a working close loop for .xlsx even. This is the code I have so far:

```
    Public Sub Open_Files()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = Range("D2").Value
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    fileName = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

    Public Sub Close_Files()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = Range("D2").Value
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks(directory & fileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
    fileName = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Let me know what I can do to create/fix this code! I really appreciate any feedback thank you!

Comment: What does "based on specific text such as "MTD", "YTD","MainFile" and "DataExtract."" should mean? Strings inside the workbooks to be open name? Or in some of their cells?

Comment: Do you want opening **all files in the respective folder** and then closing only the ones containing in their name (or in some cells) the respective strings? If inside their name, wouldn't it be better to open only the suitable ones? Then, closing only these once...

Comment: @FaneDuru Those text strings would be in the file names. So "XXXX_MTD.xlsx" or "XXXX_YTD.xlsx"

Comment: @FaneDuru This is why I come to stack overflow. That would be better for sure haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the directory, it would make more sense to loop through the `Application.Workbooks` collection. This is a collection of all currently open workbooks. You could then compare the `Workbook.Name` to your name pattern, and see if it needs to be closed.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If InStr(WB.Name, "MTD") _
        Or InStr(WB.Name, "YTD") _
        Or InStr(WB.Name, "MainFile") _
        Or InStr(WB.Name, "DataExtract") _
        Then
            WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If the list of name patterns is going to be expanded or edited frequently, it might be easier to have it declared separately. This avoids the issue of having a huge and cumbersome If Statement in the middle of the code. Instead, we can loop though an array and compare the name against each pattern individually.

```vb
Sub Example2()
    Const SEARCH_TEXTS As String = "MTD,YTD,MainFile,DataExtract"
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    
        Dim SearchText As Variant
        For Each SearchText In Split(SEARCH_TEXTS, ",")
            If InStr(WB.Name, CStr(SearchText)) Then WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Next
        
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For Example2() I'm getting a compile error at "For Each SearchText in Split(SEARCH_TEXTS, ",")" saying for Each control variable must be variant or object. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: For Example1() I'm getting a "Block If" error at the "End If" line. As I am relatively new, let me know if you have advice on how to get around that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @mmb53 Yes, sorry, I have corrected my code to resolve both issues.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust my opening file code to only open files within a directory containing the strings "MTD" "YTD" "data Extract" etc.? I know you showe3d me how to do it with closing, but opening based on those strings would help a ton

Comment: Yeah, its very similar! In your code, inside the `Do While`, with the `Workbooks.Open`. Add an If statement to that `Workbook.Open` line.  `If InStr(fileName, "MTD") Or InStr(fileName, "YTD") Or InStr(fileName, "MainFile") Or InStr(fileName, "DataExtract")  Then Workbooks.Open directory & fileName`

Comment: @mmb53 or using my second example, change the `Workbook.Open` line into a For Loop that goes through a list of matching patterns. `For Each SearchText In Split(SEARCH_TEXTS, ","):  If InStr(filename, CStr(SearchText)) Then Workbooks.Open directory & fileName: Next`

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works very efficiently and I appreciate you taking some time out of your day to reply. Helps me a ton thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub closeWorkbooks()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim directory As String: directory = Range("D2").Value
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Path = directory And wb.name Like "*.xlsx" Then
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Good Luck